# dc.js / d3 xAxis show and order Monthname in linechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Hello i have a question about dc/d3, i would like to show on the xAxis the monthname, Januar till December (in correct order)
The Value should be sum up for each year (i mean on January shoud be the Values from Year 2020 till 2022 - only one Januar)

the following code works fine for Bars because the reorder of the x in this way works fine, but for line chart i get a funny chart.

```
function Dimension() {
    return Data.ndx.dimension(function (d) { return moment.localeData()._months[d["DATE"].getMonth()]; });
}
    
function Group(thisDim) {
    var thisVal = thisDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d["VALUE"]; });
    return thisVal;
}

var thisDim = Dimension();
var thisVal = Group();
chartObject.dimension(thisDim).group(thisVal)
                .title(function (d) {   return d.key; })
                .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
                .label(function (d) {  return d.key;})
                .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 70})
                .elasticY(true)
                ;
for (var i=0;i<12;i++) x.push(moment.localeData()._months[i]);
    chartObject.x(d3.scaleBand().domain(x)).xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
```

This is a simple code (i hope i have put all in)

Here is a screenshot of the chart:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Currently [the group order must match the scale order](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/598). One way to do this is by coding months as numbers or JS dates, and then setting the tick format in order to translate to month strings.

Comment: Thanks got it working
`chartObject.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) { return moment.localeData()._months[d]; });`

Comment: Nice, thanks for following up with your solution!